# How garbage collector increases performance?

Tags: ruby

I started use Ruby 2.0 and when I was searching why Ruby 2.0, I have heard about Garbage collector uses Bitmap Marking. I am bit confused about how it will increases performance. Please help me resolve my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to copy and past the full answer here, but you can read a very detailed explanation here: http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0